# What is the easiest way to have a better quality image from a given image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, jpg

I am a novice for graphic design.

I have a low quality image which is given by my friend, its size is really small, but we want to make it bigger and clearer so that we can use it as a banner or logo or etc.

[image]

So my question is what is the easiest way to get a better quality image from a given(smaller, low quality) image?

1. **Should I manually draw it,** and **how**, **what tools** to use?
2. **Or is there a way which I can easily convert it to a vector and then increase the size and then save it back as a png?**

Comment: you have the two choice ... redraw it using any "vector base" software is so easy or trace it using the same software or you have another free online tool will do the job. http://vectormagic.com/online/how_it_works

Comment: @hsawires thank you for your reply. I tried that website, the edge of this image isn't smooth, so I'd like to re-drew it. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: So you have to redraw it from scratch. or just search the internet for a larger version and use the same website to trace it.

Comment: Your question regarding the heart image is a different question and is more technical support or software training than a design question. I removed that portion of this question in order to keep this on-topic. This question still shows an overall lack of effort and may still receive down votes or close votes. **Posting what you have tried in order to solve this yourself** may deter those votes.

Comment: @Scott Hi mate, thank you for your explanation. I got your point. I ended up drawing the outer circle by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to turn your low-resolution graphic into a high-resolution (or vector) version, you'll need to trace over it in a program like Adobe Illustrator.

Illustrator also has the "Live Trace" feature, which can quickly turn that sort of black-and-white icon into a vector instantly.

Once the image is vector, you can stretch it infinitely large or small and not lose any quality.

For your second item about the heart, I really don't have any idea. You should post your questions as separate anyways, it becomes really confusing trying to answer two different things at once.

Comment: If the OP were to use Live Trace, he might have improved results if he enlarges the image 5 or 6 times, blurs it slightly, and saves as greyscale. This way the pixelation itself does not get traced.

Comment: I mark this post as my answer as it answers my question. But I ended up drawing it myself :) because after cutt off the irrelevant parts from the original image, the edges of the outter circle became not smooth. thank you KoldBane